# Connect to Pi using SSH without having internet

Tags: ssh

I have an Ethernet cable from my MacBook to my Pi.
I would like to control my Pi using SSH.

If I check `ifconfig` on the Pi then I see my `inet addr` is `169.254.132.204`.

Is it possible to set up an SSH connection?

I don't have any internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can `ssh` from macOS to Pi even using a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) which has a section discussing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH application such as PuTTY, or any. Then you can control your Raspberry by logging into it using your login ID (default: `pi`) and password (default: `raspberry`).

Their you get complete access of the terminal of Pi.

Comment: Why do you recommend PuTTY? Is it the most appropriate application for the problem described in the question?

Comment: Note that installing PuTTY on Mac OS is far from straightforward: the OP will have to install MacPorts or Homebrew first. Why not just use `ssh` command in terminal?